# Scroll view Does not show images but scrolls?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, scrollview

I am trying to learn the basics of IOS development and Ive been experimenting with different views.
I tried to make a scroll view that display an array of images which scrolls properly but none of the images appear?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imagesArray = [UIImage]()

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scroll = UIScrollView()
        scroll.isPagingEnabled = true
        scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scroll.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        return scroll
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setScrollView()
    }

    func setScrollView(){
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        imagesArray = [UIImage(named:"gamerrr"),UIImage(named:"family"),UIImage(named:"gamerrr"),UIImage(named:"family"),UIImage(named:"family")] as! [UIImage]

        setUpImages(imagesArray)
    }

    func setUpImages(_ images:[UIImage]){
        for i in 0..<images.count {
            // container of each image
            let imageView = UIImageView()
            // shifting to next image
            let xPos = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * CGFloat(i)
            // width and height of the screen
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
             // shifting to next image
            scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use collection view

Answer (score 1):

You may need to set the image

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image:images[i])
```